# Send data from Activity1 to a fragment of Activity2 by using Inent

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I want to send a string from a recyclerView of Activity1 to a fragment of Activity2 using intent. for better understanding, here is the demonstration image

[image]

so I'm fetching the key from recyclerView like this

```
    @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(EventsViewHolder viewHolder, EventDetails model, int position) {

                viewHolder.setEventDate(model.getDate());
                viewHolder.setEventIcon(getApplicationContext(),model.getIcon());
                viewHolder.setEventTitle(model.getTitle());
                viewHolder.setEventDescription(model.getDescription());
                viewHolder.setEventTotalGuest(model.getTotal_guests());

                 String guest_key = getRef(position).getKey();

                viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        Intent guestListIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GuestListActivity.class);
                        startActivity(guestListIntent);
                        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);

                    }
                });

            }
```

and now I want to send the **guestKey** by using intent from this activity to a fragment of **GuestListActivity.class**

**I've tried Bundle but I can't send data.**
TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> send the data as u send from activity to activity and receive in fragment as getActivity().getIntent() and then do as you receive data in activity.

Comment: just solved the problem by using this approach...it was really easy :)

Answer (score 3):

First, send data from activity1 to activity2

```
Intent guestListIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GuestListActivity.class);
guestListIntent.putExtra("guest_key",guest_key)
startActivity(guestListIntent);
```

Catch it in Activity 2

```
    String guest_key = "";
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bundle != null){
        guest_key = bundle.getString("guest_key","");
    }
```

Now send to Fragment of Activity 2

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("guest_key", guest_key);
    NewFragment newFragment = new NewFragment();
    newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Catch in Fragment `onCreateView`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String guest_key = getArguments().getString("guest_key","");

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_three, container, false);
}
```

Comment: String guest_key = getArguments().getString("guest_key","");

can you please check this line? the value here is replaced with " "

Comment: if there is no string found with key "guest_key" than it will return default value i.e. "" instead of null ...

Comment: @WalidAlAshik you aren't adding your extra#data to your intent. do it first then you can get it from the fragment.  follow the first part of this answer.... 
getArguments().getString("guest_key",""); 2nd parameter here is the default value if it can't find the key-data.

Comment: Thanks a lot NaveenDew and @Sadiq Md Asif. I just got this solved another way. I've just simply send intent with putExtra() from Activity1 to Activity2 and catched that string in fragment like this  String guest_key = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("guest_key");

Though, it was someone's answer.
as both answer is correct, I've accepted your answer

Comment: thanks, @Walid, glad it helped you
this is the correct approach for passing the data between activities and fragments
there are other ways also like accessing activity data directly by getActivity().data or creating a getter() in Activity but all these are not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Here, any fragment of Activity2 is being created after onCreate() of this activity.

I will suggest you to use any of two approach to receive data in a Fragment of Activity2.

**Approach 1:**

Send data using Bundle with intent and receive it in Activity2 then set as Arguments while making transition of a fragment.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("YOUR_KEY", "KEY_VALUE");
guestListIntent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(guestListIntent);
```

Receive this data in Activity2,

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
```

Set data while Fragment transition,

```
Fragment frag = new YOUR_FRAGMENT();
frag.setArguments(extras);
```

Receive data in Fragment,

```
String value=  getArguments().getString("YOUR_KEY");
```

**Approach 2:**

Declare static variable. Assign value inside onClick then access and use this value from fragment class

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the data to `GuestListActivity` and retrive the data in `GuestListActivity`. After that when you do the fragment tracation or add the fragment pass the data through bundle. Then you will be able to get the data in your desire fragment. For better understanding see the demonstration image.

[image]

send data to `GuestListActivity`

```
@Override
protected void populateViewHolder(EventsViewHolder viewHolder, EventDetails model, int position) {

    // other code of view holder

    viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent guestListIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GuestListActivity.class);
            guestListIntent.putExtra("guest_key",guest_key)
            startActivity(guestListIntent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
            }
    }
}
```

Retrieve the data in `GuestListActivity`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String guest_key = "";
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bundle != null){
        guest_key = bundle.getString("guest_key","");
    }
}
```

Send the data to your fragment

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("guest_key", guest_key);
MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
myFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Retrieve data in your fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String guest_key = getArguments().getString("guest_key","");
}
```

Comment: vaiya where i use for sending the data to fragment codes 

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("guest_key", guest_key);
MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
myFragment.setArguments(bundle);

in My Activity1 where I made the intent or GuestListActivity? 
bit confused !!

Comment: vaiya please check this piece of code once again..app is getting crashed every time

Comment: start the `GuestListActivity` as it is but add the data to with the intent. In the `GuestListActivity` `onCreate` retrieve the data using the same key and pass it to the fragment. See the update answer

Comment: i've tried this but app got crashed with NullPointerException 
String guest_key = getArguments().getString("guest_key","");

in this line getString("gueust_key", "NULL"); 
vaiya please see here is the default value is NULL

also Bundle is being created two times. So where I'll add Bundle bundle = new Bundle()
for fragment arguments?

Comment: this is a sample code to understand the steps and mechanism..If it shows NULL value then check the and key. It must be same and also same data type.